# SDL installation failure on windows with MinGW - dvec.h error

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, sdl-2

I am trying to set up SDL on Windows and am struggling.

I am trying to follow [LazyFoo's tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/mingw/index.php) on a fresh install of Windows 8 32bit.

- I install `MinGW` via the link to the mingw-get-setup.exe from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/, and then install it and update the basic packages.
- I download the developer libraries for `SDL2-2.0.0` (in order to follow the tutorial exactly, because the current w.0.3 didn't work neither.) and extract the main folder to C:/, which then within it includes folders named `i686-w64-mingw32` and `x86_64-w64-mingw32` (what is the difference between these exactly?), as well as two other folders called 'include' and 'lib' (what exactly is the difference between these lib&include folders from the ones within the i686-w64-mingw32 and x86_64-w64-mingw32 folders?)
- I copy his source code file or make my own simple test file that basically just includes a main() with 'return 0;' and an '#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
- then I run the cmd line from the tutorial, below, and I get the following failed result:

`C:\01_hello_SDL>g++ 01_hello_SDL.cpp -IC:\mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2 -LC:\mingw_dev_lib\lib -w-Wl,-subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o 01_hello_SDL
    In file included from c:\mingw\i686-w64-mingw32\include\intrin.h:151:0,
                 from C:\mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2/SDL_cpuinfo.h:44,
                 from C:\mingw_dev_lib\include\SDL2/SDL.h:71,
                 from 01_hello_SDL.cpp:5:
c:\mingw\i686-w64-mingw32\include\dvec.h: In function 'const __m128i get_mask128()':c:\mingw\i686-w64-mingw32\include\dvec.h:56:83: error: '_mm_set1_epi64' was notdeclared in this scope
   static const __m128i mask128 = _mm_set1_epi64(M64((__int64)0xffffffffffffffffll));`

This is them followed by a ton of errors and I ctrl-c.

Any advice would be appreciated. thanks!

-Dan

Answer (score -1):

dvec.h in mingw-w64 is broken - you need to edit it and replace

`#ifdef __SSE__`

with

`#ifdef __SSE2__`

Comment: Do you have any proof/source for your statement?

Comment: Please explain your answer